# Retrieving data from sql to datagridview using LinqToSql

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql

I have a datatable in sql and a datagridview in winform. datatable holds measurement results from a mould with a MouldID. For every measurement 50 lines of results are logged to table. To track measurement count for same mould, i also have MeasId column which incremented by 1 for every measurement input. Please see picture for table view.
[image: Table Screenshot]
What i need to do, retrieve only the rows with choosen MouldID (from a combobox) with last MeasID.
I tried following codes but i couldn't figure out how to group this rows with MeasId.

```
using (LinqDataClassesDataContext dataContext = new 
LinqDataClassesDataContext())
{
    // attemp 1
    var query=dataContext.SupplierVals                   
            .Where(m=>m.MouldID==comboBMouldID.SelectedValue.ToString())
            .OrderByDescending(m => m.MeasId).FirstOrDefault();

    // attemp 2
    var query=dataContext.SupplierVals                      
            .Where(mr=>mr.MouldID==comboBMouldID.SelectedValue.ToString())
            .OrderByDescending(mr => mr.MeasId).Select();

    // attemp 3
    var query = (from x in dataContext.SupplierVals
               where x.MouldID == comboBMouldID.SelectedValue.ToString()
               select x).First(); 

    // attemp 4
    var query = from x in dataContext.SupplierVals
            where x.MouldID == comboBMouldID.SelectedValue.ToString()
            group x by x.MeasId into grp
            select grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.MeasId).First();

daGridUnused.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
daGridUnused.Columns["unusedShowDist"].DataPropertyName = "Distnc";
daGridUnused.Columns["unusedShowAper"].DataPropertyName = "Apert";
daGridUnused.Columns["unusedShowTap"].DataPropertyName = "Taper";

daGridUnused.DataSource = query;

}
```

None of these queries return what i need from datatable.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Whole project is built-up with linq, so i am kinda stuck with it now

Comment: " with last MeasID. " does that mean the most recent entry from all of the entries with the highest MeasID ?

Comment: @MongZhu Yes, exactly. With the highest MeasId count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you were almost there. You simply need to filter also by the Max value and order by the `ValueId`:

```
string mouldId = comboBMouldID.SelectedValue.ToString();
int max = dataContext.SupplierVals                   
        .Where(m=>m.MouldID == mouldId)
        .Max(m => m.MeasId);
var query=dataContext.SupplierVals                   
        .Where(m=>m.MouldID == mouldId && m.MeasId == max).ToList();
```

disclaimer: this query can surely be optimized, I am working on a better solution

Comment: FYI, it didn't return any data from table also.

Comment: This is the challenge actually. Now on the table, there is only 1 MouldID and 3 MeasId for this mould. But in real app, there will be lots of MouldIDs and measurements for them. Data needs to be distinguished by these 2 paramater. I need rows displays (let2

Comment: @TeoLaferla this is not the point, the point is that you have multiple rows having the same `MouldId`, the same `MeasId` and even the **same** `Date`! From your examply it seems that you can distinguish them only by the column `ValueID`. How far away from the reality is your posted example? I cannot read minds, I can only provide a solution for the **posted** problem according to your description

Comment: This is exactly my real application. As i said now on table there is only one MouldId but i can populate more if you need

Comment: @TeoLaferla ok it seems I express myself very unclear :) look at the rows 26, 27 and 28 in your table. All of them have the same values in the corresponding columns. Which row would you expect as the returning result of your query?

Comment: Is it not possible to select rows with highest MeasId for a MouldID then group them?

Comment: "select rows with highest MeasId for a MouldID then group them?" group by what? it seems that you want a single result, because you used `FirstOrDefault()` so which of the rows `26, 27 and 28` would be the final candidate?

Comment: For this instance, i need rows starting from 16 to 28. So you don't think it is not possible to get with these parameters?

Comment: We can filter it by date. I don't know how this happened. But in real app, i don't think data input will be this serial. this instance was just a coincedence.

Comment: And i just remember, that's actually why i had added the date column. to filter data. Otherwise i don't need it.

Comment: @TeoLaferla ok then simply remove the orderby clause. I got distracted , because you used in 3 of 4 of your posted queries either `First` or `FirstOrDefaul`. I thought you need only 1 row. I edited my post. Have a look

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was it.

Comment: @TeoLaferla no problem, glad I could help